# Delete specifically named subfolder older than a specific date from subfolders

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a few network drives that have files and subfolders older than a specific date cleared out routinely.

To remove subfolders I tend to use something like this (after mapping the network share to R:): 
`forfiles /P "R:" /D -200 /C "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path" >> %backuplog% 2>&1`

However, I have a folder structure that now fills with folders with names that are not predictable (so I couldn't map them directly very easily), e.g.

```
R:/423423423/SIS.d/
R:/543543534/SIS.d/
R:/765465477/SIS.d/
```

each of the subfolders within R: has a number of files and folders, but I would like to delete all the subfolders named SIS.d older than 6months from within them.  Is it possible to modify the forfiles command to do this?  If not, can anyone help with another method?

Could I use something like 
`/m */SIS.d/*.*` ?

thanks,
Phil

Comment: maybe just a for loop added? I did not test this as I am on my phone, it is just to give you an idea. `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /ad R: ^| findstr SIS.d') do forfiles /P %%i /D -200 /C "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path" >> %backuplog% 2>&1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use command **FORFILES** for this task despite its name.

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "R:\" /M "SIS.d" /S /D -200 /C "%ComSpec% /C if @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path >>"%backuplog%" 2>&1" 2>nul
```

**FORFILES** searches

- in root directory of drive `R:` because of option `/P "R:\"`
- and all its subdirectories because of option `/S`
- for an entry (file or directory) matching case-insensitive the search mask `SIS.d` because of `/M "SIS.d"`
- being older than 200 days because of `/D -200` according to last modification date

and executes for each found entry because of option `/C "..."` the command line:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C if @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path >>"%backuplog%" 2>&1
```

`%backuplog%` is also expanded before execution of command `forfiles` and expands hopefully to a full qualified file name without enclosing double quotes specified extra on the command line.

`cmd.exe` first runs command **IF** for a case-sensitive comparison if the string passed by `forfiles` with `@isdir` to the command is equal the string `TRUE`.

On this string comparison condition being true, `cmd.exe` runs command **RD** to quietly remove the directory with all its subdirectories and files specified with the full qualified directory name referenced with `@path` and passed by `forfiles` to `cmd.exe` always enclosed in double quotes.

The standard output and the error output of command **RD** is redirected to file of which name is assigned to environment variable `backuplog`. Command **RD** never outputs something to handle **STDOUT** on usage of the options `/S` and `/Q`. **RD** will output an error message to handle **STDERR** if complete deletion of the directory fails for various reasons. So it would be enough to use just `2>>"%backuplog%"` instead of `>>"%backuplog%" 2>&1`.

The complete deletion of a directory currently processed by `forfiles` results in an error message by `forfiles` to handle **STDERR** which is suppressed by additional `2>nul` at end of `forfiles` command line.

**Note:** The directory separator on Windows is `\` (backslash) and not `/` (forward slash). `/` is used on Windows for options as it can be seen here on this command line very well. So don't write command lines with dependency on automatic correction of Windows file system kernel functions by using wrong `/` instead of `\` in file and directory argument strings.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cmd /?`
- `forfiles /?`
- `if /?`
- `rd /?`

See also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)).